# How do I overload my function so it can take an array in c#?

Tags: c#

I wrote a function and it seems to work for two values (int r, int x) but now i need to overload that and use an array instead so that it takes (int r, array). How would i go about this? The size of the array isn't too important here, it will be taking a small few numbers like 8 27 64 etc .

```
  static double rthRoot (double r, double x)
    {

        double y = double.NaN;
        if (x > 0)
        {
            y = Math.Exp((Math.Log(x)) / r);
        }

        if (r % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (x < 0)
            {
                y = -(Math.Exp((Math.Log(Math.Abs(x))) / r));
            }
        }

        return y;

    }int[] myArray;
        myArray = new int[] { 8, 27, 64, 125 };
```

I want to overload this function but instead of double x i want to use an array such as the one at the end

Comment: Your question is unclear. Array parameters aren't any different than any other kind of parameter. You are still passing a value to the method, and your parameter list indicates the type. Overloads work the same with array parameters as with any other type. Edit your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain what _specifically_ you are having trouble getting to work. Be sure to include the _exact text_ of any error or exception, and for exceptions, a complete stack trace. Make sure your question also explains what you've researched so far.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to overload the return value?

Answer (score 0):

By overload you mean something like this?

```
    static double rthRoot(double r, double x) //1
    {
        //original
        double y = double.NaN;
        if (x > 0)
        {
            y = Math.Exp((Math.Log(x)) / r);
        }

        if (r % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (x < 0)
            {
                y = -(Math.Exp((Math.Log(Math.Abs(x))) / r));
            }
        }

        return y;

    }
    static double rthRoot(double r, int[] x) //2
    {
        //overload
        double y = double.NaN;
        //whatever

        return y;

    }
```

If you pass an `int[]` for the second parameter it will go to method 2.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

```
static double[] rthRoot(double r, double[] xs)
{
    return xs.Select(x => rthRoot(r, x)).ToArray();
}

static double[] rthRoot(double r, int[] xs)
{
    return xs.Select(x => rthRoot(r, (double)x)).ToArray();
}
```

Both rely on your current definition of `rthRoot` to work.